# Split the input

Tags: c

I ask user to enter something like "a letter+a number". A1, B3, H7 etc.
The number is always < 9.

My code:

```
int number;
char letter;

scanf("%s%d", &letter, &number);

printf("%s%d", &letter, number);
```

But it works only if the variables are entered with a space. "b 3" works, but "b3" doesn't.

How to split the input correctly and assign the letter and the number to the variables as in the code above?

Answer (score 2):

I strongly advise reading man 3 printf.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    int number;
    char letter;

    scanf("%c%d", &letter, &number);

    printf("%c%d", letter, number);
    return 0;
}
```